# list::back() causes stack overflow

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

My application compiles without any error/warning. At runntime I'm getting a strange stack overflow when calling the list::back() function (@std::_Iterator_base12::_Orphan_me() Line 193).

```
class Stock
{
public:
    bool falling = false;
    list<int> peaks;
    list<int> bottoms;

    void ProcessOption(int value)
    {
        if (falling)
        {
            if (bottoms.empty()) {
                bottoms.push_back(value);
                return;
            }

            int& lastValue = bottoms.back(); //<- Error
            if (value < lastValue) {
                bottoms.pop_back();
                bottoms.push_back(value);
            }
            else if (value > lastValue) {
                falling = false;
                ProcessOption(value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (peaks.empty()) {
                peaks.push_back(value);
                return;
            }

            int& lastValue = peaks.back(); //<- Error
            if (value > lastValue) {
                peaks.pop_back();
                peaks.push_back(value);
            }
            else if (value < lastValue) {
                falling = true;
                ProcessOption(value);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The debugger confirms that both lists including one (valid) element when calling the function. I've tested it with up-to-date MSVC++ 2013 and 2015 compiler.

Comment: I think you have infinite recurse of ProcessOption function, but it crashed in line with back().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact line where you get the error is not the root cause. The underlying issue is that `ProcessOption()` keeps calling itself until you run out of stack space.

To confirm this, use your debugger to examine the call stack at the point of the crash.

Comment: Argh, thank you very much! I comared the wrong value for recursive call...